# How to indicate to browser credentials should be saved without doing a page reload

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have the following html

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="doLogin();">Login</button>
</form>
```

doLogin() just makes an Ajax call to a web service that takes care of the logging in.
But when I take this approach in Firefox it does not prompt to save the login credentials.

Is there a way I can indicate to the browser that the credentials should be saved?

Comment: Why not handle the form submission instead?

Comment: My web app is a reactive one. In short, it uses Ajax service calls to update its DOM tree.  So form submission does not fit the design.

Comment: Ah, but it still does!  Instead of handling `onclick`, use `onsubmit` on the form.  You'll find that your login form is more compatible with a lot of things, such as pressing enter on a password field for example.  I don't know if this will solve your specific problem in Firefox but it's likely, and it will solve other problems as well.  Just make sure to call `e.preventDefault()` on the even so that the form doesn't actually submit to the server.

Answer (score 0):

As per Brad's comments I needed to handle it in my onsubmit event doing a event.preventDefault() to stop the page from reloading:

```
<form class="form-inline" onsubmit="doLogin(event)">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>

function doLogin(event) {
  console.log("Make the Ajax call to login");
  event.preventDefault();
}
```